# Scale object along surface towards pivot for hair growth effect

Tags: transforms

I am trying to achieve an animation effect of a character's hair growing out to it's final form. The hair is basically a bunch of curved hair card strips and it seemed like the best way to achieve the effect was to make a blendshape and just scale the geometry along their original path. I could achieve the effect I'm looking for by manually moving all the edges of each strip towards the "source" but that would take ages. I have a potential idea for how a script could pull it off, but before I dive into that I figured I should check and see if there's an easier option that I'm just missing.

Here's a simple image to help illustrate what I want to do. I want to "shrink" each polygon along the (poorly draw) curve towards the "pinned" edge
[image]

Edit: Here's what the hair I'm using looks like currently

[image]

Comment: Are the cards 'live' deformed along curves using a modifier, or fixed? Are they UV mapped? Maybe you could use a shader?

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not suit your case simply to use an extrusion of a curve, rather than deformed geometry? You could use the Data tab > Geometry panel > 'End Mapping' of a curve with multiple splines to grow ribbons:

[image]

There are other more flexible options, maybe using an actual Hair particle system.. but this is simple..

Comment: That's certainly a great idea for the future, but alas won't work in my case as the hair I'm working with is already completed and needing to remain the same in terms of vertices count...

Comment: @GiantDwarf010 Is the hair already curved? Could you share a sample?

Comment: sure, I've edited the post to have the hair. It's a pretty complex model but other than the skullcap, it's all a series of polygonal strips